# Запуск консольной команды и получение её ответа с помощью Python 3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Как можно написать программу на Python 3 для линукса, чтобы она вбивала в терминал команду и считывала ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать функцию [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) из модуля 
`subprocess`:

```
subprocess.check_output('ls file; exit 0', shell=True)
```

Здесь `shell=True` нужно использовать, если вся команда идёт в виде одной строки,
а `; exit 0` добавлено для того, чтобы не бросалось исключение в случае, если команда вернёт не нулевой код.

Можно контролировать код возврата, используя блок `try-except`, отлавливая ошибки запущенных команд:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('ls file', shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Команда \n> {}\nзавершилась с кодом {}'.format(e.cmd, e.returncode))
```

Если нужно учитывать и поток `stderr`, то документацией предлается следующий способ:

```
subprocess.check_output("ls file; exit 0", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Здесь мы явно получаем нулевой код возврата, подавляя поднятие исключения, а также перенаправляем поток `stderr` на `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = input('--> ')  
--> Monty Python's Flying Circus
>>> s  
"Monty Python's Flying Circus"
```

Comment: Скорее всего, это немного не то, что просит автор вопроса.